# When in the F-test the restricted and unrestricted regressions both have independent variables, must they be the same ones?

Tags: regression, f-test

I've been given a task related to F-tests, in which I'm asked to explain why regression (1) is a restricted version of (2). However, the independent variables are transformed for regression b. As an example to clarify: regression (1) is b0 + b1 x Y1 - b2 x Y2 and regression (2) is b0z  + b1z x Y1/Z. Without the transformed variable I'd simply say that (2) is a restricted version of (1) because slope coefficient b2 has been assumed to be equal to 0, removing the term from the regression.

That is what I've understood from my handbook (Stock&Watson's Introduction to Econometrics): in a restricted regression one or more slope coefficients of the unrestricted versions are assumed to be 0. It says nothing about whether it's fine to transform the variables between the unrestricted and restricted regressions. I'd think it isn't because that'd seem to defeat the point of the F-test.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the equations as$\ LaTeX$. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: Are you going to respond to my question after I've edited the post?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer ... but if you edit your post, making it better readable, more people might be inclined to answer! Keep in mind that each week, this site sees about 600 questions, but only about  half that number of answers, unfortunately. So you are participating in a competion about attention, so clear and well-written, well-layout questions have an advantage!